# Accessing a method which is not on the base Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I have a design issue and am looking for the best design solution. I have added an example of the issue below.

```
public interface IVehicle<T>
{
    int GetEngineSize();
}

public class Car : IVehicle<Car>
{
    public int GetEngineSize()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool HasSpolier()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Bus : IVehicle<Bus>
{
    public int GetEngineSize()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseController<T>
{
    public IVehicle<T> Repository { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CarController : BaseController<Car>
{
    public CarController()
    {
        // How can I access the HasSpolier method from the IVehicle<T> without having to cast the Interface to concrete class Car
        bool result = Repository.HasSpolier();
    }
}
```

Comment: HasSpoiler is a method of the class Car, not IVehicle<T> so you cannot access it without casting up to Car again. Why does the Car Controller care if there is a spoiler?

Comment: I think, `IVehicle` doesn't need to be generic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your generics are doing what you want here.

If instead of

```
IVehicle<T> Repository {get; set;}
```

You did

```
T Repository {get; set;}
```

You could make

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> where T : IVehicle
```

To ensure that they're of the IVehicle Interface

Then you'd have a typed repository and get access to your spoiler method.

You're doing `IVehicle<Bus>` but at least in the sample code, the T is never used in the interface.  At this point the T is worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you implement the method in the interface, you can't access it without casting it to another class.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to cast your Repository to Car.

It would make using your interface pointless as the dependency on the implementation which you're trying to remove is re-introduced.

Also the type parameter on your interface isn't required, you don't use it anywhere else in the interface...

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    int GetEngineSize();
}
```

Comment: Appologies I should have removed that it was due to me stripping down the code.